# Can an iPhone 7 or later using iOS 11+ act as an NFC tag?

Tags: ios, nfc, nfc-p2p

I understand that an iPhone 7 or later will be able to read certain NFC tags under certain conditions however will an iPhone also be able to act as an NFC tag or "display"/share any sort of unique NDEF data that can be read by other devices with NFC reading capabilities?

Comment: Not really had a hands-on with NFC though, but I believe for now we have only read capability and not write. So iPhone behaving as a tag or display data might not be possible. Not sure though

Answer (score 3):

Not at this time.  Using [CoreNFC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc) in iOS 11 an iPhone 7(+) can read NDEF data from NFC tags but not act as a tag.

Comment: Is there any way to share/display readable NDEF data without acting as a tag?

Comment: I guess you could encode equivalent data in something like a QR code

Comment: Still seems true in iOS 12. Have you seen announcements suggesting otherwise?